# cdk deploy in a docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cdk

I am trying to run the `aws cdk` on a CI/CD pipeline.

The pipeline runs everything in a docker container.

When the `cdk deploy` step is run, it requires the docker daemon to run docker build and push an imace to ECR.

I am running into the error:

```
Error: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:156:25)
    at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:147:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:787:11)
    at Socket._write (net.js:799:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
    at Socket.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/node_modules/cdk-assets/lib/private/shell.ts:28:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.shell (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/node_modules/cdk-assets/lib/private/shell.ts:26:10)
    at Docker.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/node_modules/cdk-assets/lib/private/docker.ts:75:13)
```

Not sure how to get around this, is this a limitation of the aws cdk?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially your CI/CD process needs to be able to handle Docker in Docker if you run all of your builds in containers.  Create a mock CI/CD pipeline that just runs `docker image ls` or something like that to see if docker is working.  In order to do docker with CDK, the server the CDK command is running on must have docker.

I've seen the EPIPE error when docker isn't even installed.